# Is there a way to make use of two custom, complete functions in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to achieve the following in Vim?

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=customlist,CustomFunc1 -complete=customlist,CustomFunc2 Foo call MyFunction(<f-args>)
```

The user will be able to tab-complete **two** arguments when calling the function Foo from Vim command line. The auto-complete will pull from two different lists.

E.g.:

```
:Foo arg1 good<TAB> whi<TAB>
```

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes the words:

```
:Foo arg1 goodyear white
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is sufficient information passed to completion function through
its arguments. Knowing current cursor position in the command line to
be completed, it is possible to determine the number of the argument
that is currently being edited. Here is the function that returns
that number as the only completion suggestion:

```
" Custom completion function for the command 'Foo'
function! FooComplete(arg, line, pos)
    let l = split(a:line[:a:pos-1], '\%(\%(\%(^\|[^\\]\)\\\)\@<!\s\)\+', 1)
    let n = len(l) - index(l, 'Foo') - 1
    return [string(n)]
endfunction
```

Substitute the last line with a call to one of the functions
completing specific argument (assuming they are already written).
For instance:

```
    let funcs = ['FooCompleteFirst', 'FooCompleteSecond']
    return call(funcs[n], [a:arg, a:line, a:pos])
```

Note that it is necessary to ignore whitespace-separated words before
the command name, because those could be the limits of a range, or
a count, if the command has either of them (spaces are allowed in both).

The regular expression used to split command line into arguments takes
into account escaped whitespace which is a part of an argument, and
not a separator. (Of course, completion functions should escape
whitespace in suggested candidates, as usual in case of the command
having more than one possible argument.)

Comment: Great, thanks! I can get a working solution from this, will investigate more later.

Answer (score 5):

There's no built-in way for vim to do this. What I'd do in this situation is embed the logic into the completion function. When you set `-complete=customlist,CompletionFunction`, the specified function is invoked with three arguments, in this order:

- The current argument
- The entire command line up to this point
- The cursor position

So, you can analyze these and call another function depending on whether it looks like you're on the second parameter. Here's an example:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=customlist,FooComplete Foo call Foo(<f-args>)
function! Foo(...)
  " ...
endfunction

function! FooComplete(current_arg, command_line, cursor_position)
  " split by whitespace to get the separate components:
  let parts = split(a:command_line, '\s\+')

  if len(parts) > 2
    " then we're definitely finished with the first argument:
    return SecondCompletion(a:current_arg)
  elseif len(parts) > 1 && a:current_arg =~ '^\s*$'
    " then we've entered the first argument, but the current one is still blank:
    return SecondCompletion(a:current_arg)
  else
    " we're still on the first argument:
    return FirstCompletion(a:current_arg)
  endif
endfunction

function! FirstCompletion(arg)
  " ...
endfunction

function! SecondCompletion(arg)
  " ...
endfunction
```

One problem with this example is that it would fail for completions that contain whitespace, so if that's a possibility, you're going to have to make more careful checks.